# How to get current connections to resources on a server with C# (similar to output from the "net file" command)

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, wmi, netapi32

In command prompt, if `net file` is executed, it shows the resources that are open over any shared folders and it also shows the user name that is accessing the resource.

Example:
[image: net file example]

The same information can be viewed from Computer Management (compmgmt.msc) -> System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Open Files.

Example:
[image: computer management open files example]

The same information can be accessed using a VBScript:

```
Set objConnection = GetObject("WinNT://localhost/LanmanServer")
Set colResources = objConnection.Resources
For Each objResource in colResources
    Wscript.Echo "Path: " & objResource.Path
    Wscript.Echo "User: " & objResource.User
    Wscript.Echo
Next
```

How can this same information by accessed via C#? (without running the `new file` command from C# - this would truncate long path names in resources).

Is it possible to get to this information using WMI (which class? - I believe `Win32_ServerConnection` doesn't give the path of the resources that are open; same with `Win32_ServerSession`) or Netapi32.dll? If so, how can this be done?

**Note:** Need a way to get the **full path** of the file that is opened similar to the information in the screenshots from command prompt and computer management.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever get a reply on this?  I need to figure this out too....

Comment: unfortunately, no